# Displaying external SQL-table as paginated list

Tags: database, 7

The following code works well for displaying a paginated list of Drupal users.

```php
function generate_list() {
  $query = db_select('users', 'u')
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->fields('u', array('name', 'uid'))
    ->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
    ->limit(20);

  $result = $query->execute();

  $list = array();
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $list[] = sprintf('<a href="/user.php?id=DE%u">%s</a>', $row->uid, $row->name);
  }

  $theme_args = array('items' => $list, 'type' => 'ul');
  return theme('item_list', $theme_args) . theme('pager');
}
```

I tried fetching from an external SQL-table using the following code.

```php
function generate_list() {
  $query = db_select('pref_users', 'u')
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->fields('u', array('first_name', 'id'))
    ->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
    ->limit(20);

  $result = $query->execute();

  $list = array();
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $list[] = sprintf('<a href="/user.php?id=%s">%s</a>', $row->id, $row->first_name);
  }

  $theme_args = array('items' => $list, 'type' => 'ul');
  return theme('item_list', $theme_args) . theme('pager');
}
```

I get this error.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7
> ERROR: relation "drupal_pref_users" does not exist at character 67:
> SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression FROM (SELECT 1 AS expression
> FROM {pref_users} u) subquery; Array() in method
> PagerDefault->execute() (line 75 in file includes/pager.inc).

Does anybody please know a way to tell Drupal to fetch data from *pref_users* and not from *{pref_users}* at it seems to do?

Comment: I suggest you simplify your question to basically something like "Can I use external tables with db_select()?". Right now, 90% of your question looks like a duplicate of your others, existing questions and it's not relevant for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the squiggly brackets are used for escaping table names in drupal. For cases where you have multiple sites in one database.

I'm guessing that you have a db prefix set up for all of your Drupal tables to be drupal_

You can set this on a db connection before `$result = $query->execute();` using the [setprefix](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/DatabaseConnection%3a%3asetPrefix/7) method

Something like

```
 $query->setprefix(array(
     'default'   => 'drupal_',
     'perf_users'     => ''));
```

*untested code*

may do it. However you are more likely to want to change your settings.php file and set table prefixs in there